# How does one persist a extension attribute in the Order addresses?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, address, address-attribute

I created a extension attribute for my customer addresses using [this tutorial](http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html).

How can I copy them to the order addresses when I finish the checkout and display them in the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an event to your module. In a event is transport the values from object to object. Example Quote Address to Order Address

Take a look at this example module to add a custom field to the billing address in the checkout.

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExtraCheckoutAddressFields

Comment: wow this looks just like what I need! gonna try it out soon and give you feedback.